# Automatic on premise server deployment

Tags: windows, virtualization, deployment, automation, scvmm

I'm new to automatic deployment and would like guidance from experts on the the best way to efficiently deploy approximately 75 vms (both windows and linux vms) on 7 vmware esxi 5.5 hosts (All hosts are at the same site)
.

The hosts may be insatlled manually because 7 hosts is not a large number; even though suggestions for automating this step are greatly appreciated.

What tools would you suggest to efficiently deploy a mix of windows and linux vms ? Can Microsoft's SCVMM achieve this ? What alternatives are suggested ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to deploy images or do configuration management on the hosts as well?

Comment: Ideally deploy images, but deploying multiple stock OSs to VMs would also save me alot of time when compared with manually deploying vms.

Comment: I assume you use vCenter, in which case you could do it with the vCenter API, simply configure a template. Problem with config management is that for example AD does not work with linux of course. I know that puppet has a powershell module, so you could use that to do everything both on linux and windows.

Comment: Have you looked at Chef? https://www.chef.io/ Infrastructure as Code might be what you are looking for? Also look into PowerCLI. That is VMware's implementation of PowerShell.

Comment: @TimHaintz I was after something with a GUI